# How to password protect private files

Tags: 8, files

I would like to protect private files with password in a content. For example, I created a content with some files, this field "Protected files" uses private filesystem.

I would like to protect these files in order to anonymous users can download these ones with a correct password.

How can I achieve this in Drupal 8?

Comment: An anonymous user with a password is an authenticated user, isn't it? Looking at it that way, everything's already built in to be able to do that with permissions

Comment: I mean, I would define a global password for protected files like other modules do for nodes.

Comment: If it was me I'd be considering whether that's really worth the effort - a global password is pretty much as good as no password. But either way, I suspect you could solve it using [`hook_file_download`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!File!file.api.php/function/hook_file_download/8.2.x) and adding a custom authorisation header

Comment: Does this go the direction you need: https://www.drupal.org/project/protected_file? Alternatively, using webforms is a decent way to protect content. Webforms would allow you to ask for emails, passwords, anything. And you could utilize a form submit hook() or such to deliver, or direct to, your protected content. I recently worked on a D7 project where we coupled webforms with view modes asking users to enter their email to download content.